# Pidgin unable to connect to GTalk

Tags: 12.10, pidgin

I can't believe I'm raising this question after years, but after a fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.10, I'm unable to connect Pidgin to Google Talk.

I use a Google Apps domain name, and the settings that I'm using are :

```
Protocol : XMPP
Username : ****
Domain   : ********.com
Resource : Home
```

In the `advanced` tab,

```
Connection security : Require encryption.
UNCHECK Allow plaintext auth over unencrypted steams
Connect port  : 5222
Connect sever : talk.google.com
File transfer proxies : proxy.eu.jabber.org
Bosh URL : (blank)
```

In the `proxy` tab,

```
No proxy.
```

I had used these same settings on 12.04 and it had worked like a charm.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using two-factor auth? Do you need to create an app-specific password?

Answer (score 3):

Use the following setting and check if it works:

```
Connection Security : "Use old-style SSL"
     Connect port   : 5223
     Connect sever  : talk.google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine works with the following differences:

- Resource: blank
- Domain: google.com (unless you are running your own XMPP server on your domain)
- Connect server: blank
- Proxy type: Use Gnome Proxy Setting

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I edited the /etc/environment as

```
http_proxy=http://<username>:<password>@<proxy_address>:<proxy_port>
```

and in pidgin, used as use environment variables

Answer (score -2):

Mind  I am using the same

1. go to the file
2. go to account 
   3 go to buddy account

then add/edit 
and then later

it should look like this

same with the first answers

Protocol : XMPP
Username : ****
Domain   : ********.com
Resource : Home
In the advanced tab,

Connection security : Require encryption.
UNCHECK Allow plaintext auth over unencrypted steams
Connect port  : 5222
Connect sever : talk.google.com
File transfer proxies : proxy.eu.jabber.org
Bosh URL : (blank)
In the proxy tab,

No proxy.

then after that you are done

Comment: Welcome to [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/tour)! Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/questions/264623/pidgin-unable-to-connect-to-gtalk/552226#552226) your post as a [clear answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer). Read [Editing help page](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help)